# IOS Home Widget Background not updating

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update the background of my iOS home widget with an image which is added the target.

The code for the View is really simple

```
struct HomeWidgetEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    VStack.init(alignment: .center, spacing: 2, content: {
        Image("widget_bg1")
        Text(entry.title0).bold().font(.body)
        Text(entry.title1).bold().font()
        Text(entry.title2).font(.body)
        Text(entry.time).bold().font(.title3)
      }
    ).background(
        Image("widget_bg1")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    ).padding().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

}

Here 'widget_bg1.png' is in current target assets.
But it is not showing as widget background. Not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your content in [ZStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack):

```
struct HomeWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("widget_bg1")
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                Text(entry.title0).bold().font(.body)
                Text(entry.title1).bold().font()
                Text(entry.title2).font(.body)
                Text(entry.time).bold().font(.title3)
            }
        }.padding().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. didn't work. any other suggestion?

Comment: @Kikki are you sure it's in the widget assets?

Comment: yes. I m sure it is added to the targets.